# comparison of Fixnum with nil failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I coded like this,

```
@claim = Item.find(:something)  
unless @claim.nil?  
  if @claim >= a_condition  
    do_something
  end
end
```

Even if @claim is a nil value,It is going inside the unless condition and giving the error "comparison of Fixnum with nil failed"

What is the wrong in my code.

Comment: Sorry 4 that bad question..a newbie.. :) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a_condition` is probably the nil value that you are failing on.

Answer (score 3):

```
@claim = Item.find(:something)
unless @claim.nil?
  if @claim >= a_condition
    do_something 
  end
end
```

Is `a_condition` nil perhaps?

Comment: What is your code for? I don't see any difference from the one in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Using the code you posted, the inside of the `unless` statement will definitely *not* execute if `@claim` is nil. If you get the error message you posted on line 3 of that code, it must be because `a_condition` is nil, not `@claim`.